# Spring tag <form:option> not working with Spring Data DomainClassConverter?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring MVC and Spring Data and also have configured Spring Data's `DomainClassConverter` to automatically convert String id to the appropriate Domain class.

I'm now implementing a Order to Customer reference using the  tag using:

```
<form:select path="customer">
    <form:option value="" label="Select" />
    <form:options items="${customers}" itemValue="id" />
</form:select>
```

which results in the given HTML:

```
<select id="customer" name="customer" class="span6">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Customer A</option>
    <option value="2">Customer B</option>
    <option value="3">Customer C</option>
</select>
```

When submitting a post with e.g. Customer A selected I get a exception like:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @javax.persistence.ManyToOne nl.kapsalonreflection.domain.Customer for value ''; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!
```

Which does not make sense at all as the value received should be 1 and not ''.
I also debugged the received request params and it only contained customer=1 (as expected)

Note that the `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException` is coming from Spring Data's `DomainClassConverter` and if I remove the this converter the problem does not occur anymore.

I also debugged the `DomainClassConverter` and what I can see it tries to cover twice.
First with the String value 1 (as expected) but then another call with an empty String, causing the exception.

It get's weirder though...

When I replace `<form:option value="" label="Select" />` with the plain html element `<option value="">Select</option>` then the exception does not occur, and hence only 1 call is made to the convert method with the String 1.
The weird part is that both `<form:option value="" label="Select" />` and `<option value="">Select</option>` product the same html output...

I cannot explain the behaviour... although I seemm to have a 'workaround' with the plain html element I would like to know what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `org.apache.jasper.JasperException` indicates that exception occurs during JSP rendering, not during data binding. It's consistent with the fact that exception depends on `<form:option value="" label="Select" />` - it's thrown when this tag is being processed when rendering the form after postback.

Behaviour you observe can be explained as follows: in order to determine its selected state `<form:option>` tries to compare its value with value of a field bound to `<form:select>`. If value of the bound field is `null`, `<form:option>` simply compares its value with `null`, that's why you don't get this exception during initial form rendering. Otherwise, `<form:option>` tries to convert its `<value>` to type of the bound field, and `value = ""` causes an exception at this step.

So, you should use `null` instead of empty string for "no option selected" value:

```
<form:option value="${null}" label="Select" />
```

Comment: The `value="${null}"` did the trick. Really appreciate your help as I was completely stuck and heading the wrong way. Still can't explain why the DomainClassConverter was trying to convert twice though. Once with actual value and once with empty '' value...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to consider attaching a propery editor in this kind of scenario, because if i see the code `<form:options items="${customers}" itemValue="id" />` you are directly attaching the customers list to the options. I think its autmatically taking the toString and displaying the "Csutomer A", "Customer B" etc. Ideally you may need to use the itemLabel in the form:options tag or you may need to register a property editor and attach that in the initBinder http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion